# Loading Progress Bar IOS

Tags: ios, progress-bar, progress

```
-(void)startConnection
{ 
    NSString *urlString = GET_EVENTLIST_URL_STRING;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
    [urlString UTF8String];


    if (!url)
    {
        NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not create URL from string %@", GET_EVENTLIST_URL_STRING];
        [self.delegate didGetEventListInCorrect:reason];
        return;
    }

    theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: 30.0];

    // Set the HTTP method of the request to POST
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];



    if (!theRequest)
    {
        NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not create URL request from string %@", GET_EVENTLIST_URL_STRING];
        [self.delegate didGetEventListInCorrect:reason];
        return;
    }
    theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (!theConnection)
    {
        NSString *reason = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL connection failed for string %@", GET_EVENTLIST_URL_STRING];
        [self.delegate didGetEventListInCorrect:reason];
        return;
    }

    if (theConnection)
    {
        myData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    }

}

#pragma mark - Methods connection
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aResponse
{
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [myData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [myData appendData:theData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // finished downloading the data, cleaning up
    [self.delegate didGetEventListCorrect:myData ];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self.delegate didGetEventListInCorrect:@"Failed Connection"];
}

#pragma mark - Main method of LoginUrlConnection with NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection
+ (id) connectionGetEventList:(id<GetEventListURLConnectionDelegate>)aDelegate
{
    EventListURLConnection *getEventListUrlConnection = [[self alloc]init];

    getEventListUrlConnection.delegate = aDelegate;

    [getEventListUrlConnection startConnection];

    return getEventListUrlConnection;
}
```

Hi All, 
This is my class for url connection and in my viewcontroller Im calling this list like that: "    eventconnection = [EventListURLConnection connectionGetEventList:self];
" .. I need to use one progress bar which shows the loading process something like this " http://www.google.com.tr/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&tbo=d&biw=1063&bih=502&tbm=isch&tbnid=3fZwJc8SC_xoPM:&imgrefurl=http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/most-wanted-freebies-web-designers/&docid=VLaTiYV3nRfeXM&imgurl=http://media02.hongkiat.com/freebies-for-web-designers-2011/progress-bar.jpg&w=580&h=250&ei=jxnrUMWpOKb24QTn54CQCg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=698&vpy=185&dur=704&hovh=148&hovw=342&tx=162&ty=102&sig=114441653047551513554&page=2&tbnh=147&tbnw=319&start=16&ndsp=14&ved=1t:429,r:19,s:0,i:142 " ..How can i manage this? Any idea? Thanks in advance ..

Comment: You could use a 3rd party networking library like AFNetworking that has support for progress bars and a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UISlider for tracking the progress of the load. So assuming, you use myData for holding the content, FILE_SIZE is the size in bytes of content to be downloaded and progressView is the UISlider (actually it can also be a custom view that includes the UISlider subview and a UILabel subview that specifies the % downloaded), then following code snippet should do it...

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.myData appendData:data];
    float percentDownloaded = (float)[self.myData length]/FILE_SIZE;
    NSLog (@"PERCENT DOWNLOADED IS %d %f : %f",[self.myData length], percentDownloaded,percentDownloaded*100);
    [self.progressView setProgress:percentDownloaded];

}
```

Comment: ok but, this code that you wrote is for the nsobject class ..So how can i manage in viewcontroller?

Comment: You can just use any of the notification mechanisms available in  iOS to notify the ViewController that is managing the progress view of the percentDownloaded - e.g. use KVO to set a percentDownloaded property on the object. the viewController observes this property and updates the UI accordingly. This is no different than the typical MVC model of updating the UI based on the model changes.

Comment: I couldnt manage to get :S Could you please explain a bit more? Thanks